# Recreating a database using SqlAlchemy for individual test functions fails

Tags: python, flask, sqlalchemy

I am trying to fresh up my knowledge of Flask and SqlAlchemy.
I've done the tutorial (https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/2.0.x/tutorial/index.html)
and now I am adapting it to include SqlAlchemy. I am trying not to use the Flask-SqlAlchemy plugin assuming this would make me understand things a bit better.

However, I am running into an issue with testing. In the original tutorial a new database was created on each test-function. Resulting in a clean database with known state before starting each test.
Now I am trying to do the same with SqlAlchemy but failing. See below code example:
Two tests are defined (`test_create_app` and `test_create_another_app`). When I run them individually both pass. When I run them in a session, the second one fails.

I can confirm both tests have their own database file. Also creating the table works. But I can see the second table does not have any USERS, while I do create them.

Am I trying to do something I should not want to? Or am I doing something wrong here ?
If I look at the FastAPI docs (https://fastapi.tiangolo.com/advanced/testing-database/) on testing a database there only one database per session is created. Managing state over individual tests in some kind of other way I guess.

Any help appreciated !

```py
import sqlalchemy as sa
from sqlalchemy import create_engine, orm
from sqlalchemy.sql.expression import select
import pytest

session_factory = None

#  ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~ ORM models

SqlAlchemyBase = sa.ext.declarative.declarative_base()


class User(SqlAlchemyBase):
    __tablename__ = "user"

    id: int = sa.Column(sa.Integer, primary_key=True, autoincrement=True)
    username = sa.Column(sa.String, unique=True, nullable=False)
    password = sa.Column(sa.String, nullable=False)


USERS = [
    User(username="Güllich", password="action direct"),
    User(username="Graham", password="the island"),
]

#  ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~ Database management


def init_db(connection_url: str):
    """Initialize the database."""
    global session_factory
    if session_factory:
        raise Exception("you should run this function only once.")

    engine = create_engine(connection_url, future=True)
    session_factory = orm.sessionmaker(bind=engine)

    SqlAlchemyBase.metadata.create_all(bind=engine)


def close_db():
    """Close the database"""
    global session_factory
    if session_factory:
        session_factory.close_all()
    session_factory = None


#  ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~ Testing part.


@pytest.fixture
def dbase(tmp_path):
    sqlite_file = tmp_path / "test_db.sqlite"
    connection_string = f"sqlite+pysqlite:///{sqlite_file.as_posix()}"
    print("creating database at: %s", connection_string)
    init_db(connection_string)

    session = session_factory()

    for user in USERS:
        session.add(user)
    session.commit()
    session.close()

    yield

    close_db()


def test_create_app(dbase):
    db_session = session_factory()
    query = select(User)

    users = db_session.execute(query).scalars().all()

    assert len(users) == 2


def test_create_another_app(dbase):
    db_session = session_factory()
    query = select(User)

    users = db_session.execute(query).scalars().all()

    assert len(users) == 2
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out what is wrong with my code above:

The USERS list of sqlalchemy orm instances can -I guess obviously- only be bound to a database once. So trying to do this a second time will fail (silently unfortunately).